# I can't pass PHP variable to an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

My code is below. I try to create a login form by using PHP. It is not working, so please correct me.

```
<?php
    $mycon = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db = mysql_select_db('data', $mycon);

    $_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

    $qur = "select * from admin where username = '$_user' and password = '$_pass' ";

    $res = mysql_query($qur, $mycon);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    }
    else {
        header('Location:admin.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: where is your form ?

Comment: ^Exactly, where are you getting the `$_POST[];` from?

Comment: Oh god.. did you know that the `mysql_*` functions are being removed in PHP7 and are deprecated in the current versions?

Comment: what is your error show in your screen?

Comment: no did not know about that i trying this after long time shoud i use mysqli

Comment: @Ahosan Karim Asik its always redirecting me to admin.php my form is located in admin php

Comment: @IndrikaChamariThushanChamar your logic is suppose to do the exact thing, what do you want it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `<form>` with the method `POST` along with a hidden field, like:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
        $mycon = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        $db = mysql_select_db('data', $mycon);

        $_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        $qur = "SELECT * from admin where username = '$_user' AND password = '$_pass' ";

        $res = mysql_query($qur, $mycon);

        if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

            //Your stuff here

        }
        else {
            header('Location:admin.php');
        }
    }
?>

<form role="form" method = "POST" action = "">

    Username:
        <input type = "text" name = "user">
    Password:
        <input type = "text"   name = "pass">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "check">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

*MySQL functions are deprecated. Please switch to either [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) or [PHP Data Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community) (PDO).*

Comment: Please heed the note about the deprecation of the `mysql_` functions. What you have now is a perfect way to allow an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
    $mycon = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db = mysql_select_db('data', $mycon);

    $_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

    $qur = "select * from admin where username = '".$_user."' and password = '".$_pass."'";

    $res = mysql_query($qur, $mycon);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    }
    else {
        header('Location:admin.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Some accompanying text would be in order.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
    $mycon = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db = mysql_select_db('data', $mycon);

    $_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

    $_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);


    $qur = "select * from `admin` where `username`='{$_user}' and `password` ='{$_pass}'";


    $res = mysql_query($qur, $mycon);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

        //Here your code will work

    }
    else {

        //And here it will not work
        header('Location:admin.php');
    }
?>
```

Don't forget to check table column names.